# how to define an URL relative to the current page w jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to define some urls vars in my application.js relative to the current page

```
/* Global Variables */
var base = document.location.href;
var http_video_base = base + "assets/videos/";
var http_academy_banner_base = base + "assets/banners/";
var user_academy_banner_image = "golf.jpg";
```

but this doesn't work, when my base variable is

```
http://localhost/~yves/optimalPlayer/index.html I get an error (obviously )

Failed to load resource:   
http://localhost/~yves/optimalPlayer/index.htmlassets/banners/golf.jpg
the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I should define my base variable as being the directory containing the current page

```
http://localhost/~yves/optimalPlayer/
```

how should I define var base  to get a concatenated result being :

```
http://localhost/~yves/optimalPlayer/assets/banners/golf.jpg
```

thanks for your suggestions

Comment: how about starting with `window.location.pathname`? (And drop any specific filename that may appear at the end, e.g. `index.html`)

Comment: Why not use a relative URL?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in code?  A path of "assets/videos/" will always be relative to the current folder/document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var base = window.location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, ""),
    http_video_base = base + "assets/videos/",
    http_academy_banner_base = base + "assets/banners/",
    user_academy_banner_image = "golf.jpg";

var final = http_academy_banner_base + user_academy_banner_image;
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would probably be to just trim off everything after the final / in the base URL before using it. Put this in as your first line under `/* Global Variables */`:

```
var base = document.location.href.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '');
```

That regex replace should do the trick. It finds every non-slash immediately before the end of the line and trims them, so in this case it would turn `http://localhost/~yves/optimalPlayer/index.html` into `http://localhost/~yves/optimalPlayer/`, which is what you need.

As is always the case with regex-based solutions, though, keep in mind that there may be some weird edge cases you find where this breaks. I'm pretty comfortable saying that it should work in all reasonable cases I can think of, but you can never be absolutely sure.

**Edit:** As a couple of people pointed out in comments on your original question, relative paths are probably the better solution for you, but if you're set on using absolute paths instead, this regex approach should work.